# HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>'

Tags: java, validation, constraints, option-type

Hello guys I'm trying to get the validation on the YAML

```
- name: campo
        in: query
        schema:
          type: string
          pattern: '[S|N]' #pattern
          maxLength: 1
```

Using maven spring boot and delegate. On the RestController I added annotation `@Validated` and I'm able to validate required=true fields, but if fields are not require, as per architecture design, parameter will be `Optional<String>`. For this `java.util.Optional`, trying to test and validate, throw title error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-10-21T07:50:18.651+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "HV000030: No validator could be found for constraint 'javax.validation.constraints.Size' validating type 'java.util.Optional<java.lang.String>'. Check configuration for 'metodo.campo'",
  "path": "/%7BbasePath%7D/microservicio/metodo"
}
```

¿Anyway to solve this issue to have this `Optional<String>` validation proccessed correctly? We don't want to write all code for validation on Java if can be done on YAML + validation (@Valid and @Validated).

EDIT: The validation @Size and others is generated from YAML with open api version 3.0.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should write: `Optional<@Size String>` (which would check the size of the String inside the optional) instead of `@Size Optional<String>` (which is supposed to check the size of the optional, which is meaningless).

See [Hibernate Validator: With `java.util.Optional`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#_with_code_java_util_optional_code):

```java
package org.hibernate.validator.referenceguide.chapter02.containerelement.optional;

public class Car {

    private Optional<@MinTowingCapacity(1000) Integer> towingCapacity = Optional.empty();

    //...

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for response, I can modify target autogenerated MicroserviceApi.java and change the Size into the Optional<T> but since is swagger open api (3.0.3) who autogenerate that, should assume it's not the best practice here.

Comment: I finally change the mustache templates used to build the restController and resolve problem by changing validator inside the Optional. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The newer version [Jakarta Bean Validation 2.0](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/) newly supports `Optional` validation as of August 2019. You can find this information out at their changelog summary [2. What’s new](https://beanvalidation.org/2.0/spec/#whatsnew):

> Support for `java.util.Optional`

The only certified implementation, is [Hibernate Validator `6.0.17.Final`](http://hibernate.org/validator/releases/) as of September this year.

Consider an upgrade, ohterwise you would have to omit the size validation and perform it manually.